# Карта от гугла со своими иконками и описанием

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток

[Нашел такое](http://www.zvet.ru/shops/). т.е. карта гугла, по верх нее есть иконки фирмы, причем если карту двигать - иконки тоже двигаются. И это далеко не 1 сайт в интернете такой. Есть аналогичные сайты с еще более продвинутыми картами. Там рядом располагаются надписи, уже под картой гугла, т.е. на самой странице, и при нажатии на них без перезагрузки страницы на нужной иконке всплывает подпись - где кратенько написано описание магазина.

Господа, хотел бы за раз спросить много и получить развернутый ответ.

1. Как такая штука называется? (гугление на тему - карта гугл со своими иконками, не дало результатов за которые можно зацепиться)
2. Может ли кто подробно объяснить как сделать такую карту с иконками
3. Как сделать ссылки, при нажатии на которые на карте появлялась подпись сделанная самостоятельно

p.s. очень очень охота обойтись кодом PHP+MySQL + JS + ( возможно JQ )

Comment: Меня тоже интересует использование jQuery вместе с Google Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все такие штуки и много других можно делать через апи гуглокарт.

- [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru)
- [Demo Gallery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery?hl=ru)
- [Примеры кода](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=ru)

Comment: Уважаемый, за ссылки спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ. Но это все равно как на вопрос сколько время, сказать что сейчас 2012год. Можно хоть с простого начать, как добавить на карту маркеры-иконки? Да в примерах они есть, но код примеров различается очень сильно, и в каждом примере непонятно, что есть хорошо, а что плохо

Comment: [Вот](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=ru) пример добавления маркера на карту. Этот пример есть в списке по 3-й ссылке ответа.

В каждом примере вполне понятный и лаконичный код. Если он вызывает сложности, то стоит начать не с карт, а с изучения JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Во первых, это яндекс.карта.

Во вторых, все очень просто:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    $(function () {
        map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
        setDefaultPosition();
        //map.addControl(new YMaps.TypeControl());
        //map.addControl(new YMaps.ToolBar());
        //map.addControl(new YMaps.Zoom());
        map.enableScrollZoom();
        var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(30.5003, 50.441), {style: "default#shopIcon"});
        placemark.name = "Киев";
        placemark.description = "ул. Саксаганского, 84/86<br />(044) 246-77-99";
        map.addOverlay(placemark);      
    })
</script>
```

Можете посмотреть в исходный код на [этой странице](http://secunda.com.ua/Retail).

**UPD:** И [здесь](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/dg/concepts/geoobjects.xml) примеры добавления объектов на карту

Answer (score 1):

Изучайте jscript и АПИ картографических сервисов.

Вот ссылка на блог с обучающими статьями: [Занимательная Веб-картография](http://webmap-blog.ru/).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно,это библиотека [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/).

В **google map** такое сделать просто не реально.

Comment: Почему это не реально?